# Regarding starting point of Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I understand that main is not a starting point in Linux kernel, as kernel developers are experienced enough to customize the starting point.

Consider the following:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/uImage -initrd rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init" -dtb "versatile-pb.dtb"
```

Above, I supplied the kernel image, device tree, rootfs.img as the input to the mainline kernel, so now which file in kernel is executed first. If it is an initialization file, someone would be triggering that initialization code within the kernel image. If yes, which file does that? Please advice.

Note: looking for a clear answer, i.e. exact file in arm architecture.

Comment: Look on http://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: `main` is not an entry point of any binary on any operating system in existence. It is a function called by the system specific bootstrap code. In C++ and with gcc extension also in C you can make a lot of things happen before `main` is called!

Comment: It's actually far from clear for which file you are looking! Are you looking for the thing that corresponds to `main` of normal process (which does not exist at all; kernel is not a process), the first C function that handles initialization (it works similarly to the C runtime function that does global construction in userland) or the actual entry point, which is necessarily implemented in assembly?

Comment: Okay, let me be more clear, as soon as I execute the command above, what will be the very first thing happening, what will be the first thing cpu will execute and from where?

Comment: Are you trying to trace something from there? I is a really long way...

Comment: Yes, also I need to understand how the kernel configuration set are initialized, but that is another step.

Comment: You don't need to explain anything, just name the file and line

Comment: *"what will be the very first thing..."* -- Since you're using a **uImage** file, which is a compressed zImage file with the U-Boot header, the first code executed should be `start` in the decompression code `Linux/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entry point of Linux kernel, just like any other ELF binary, is `_start`. For ARM, it is defined in [arch/arm/boot/bootp/init.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/bootp/init.S#L23)

Comment: The answer exactly as requested. I am not sure whether it would be actually helpful. As I mentioned in the other comment, it is a _long_ way to find anything from here.

Comment: There is tag in kernel.S -> kernel_start: that is trying to access ZImage? What happens with this assembly?..You are right now I understand why it is a long process to explain, could you please refer me to an appropriate documentation.